# Своя Mesh в Particle System

Tags: unity3d

Как в системе частиц Unity заменить стандартные частицы на объемные 3D модели, например, на кубы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, просто нужно покопаться в настройках системы частиц:

Заходим в раздел Renderer и проделываем следующие шаги:

1. В Render Mode выбираем Mesh
2. В Mesh выбираем нужную модель
3. В Material **обязательно** указываем свой шейдер (Default-Diffuse для начала подойдет), **со стандартным шейдером объемные меши не работают**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате получаем примерно такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выбираю свой меш, пишет ошибку "Particle system meshes will only work with exactly one (1) sub mesh" материал стандартный

Comment: @Zero из текста ошибки все очевидно - вы не можете использовать сложные меши, состоящие из двух и более сабмешей

Comment: извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, а как преобразовать его в простой?

Comment: @Zero ну так вам виднее, что у вас за меша, у вас она состоит как минимум из 2х сабмешей, что система частиц Unity не поддерживает